# What are the fastest full-text search algorithms/APIs (open source or commercial)?

Tags: algorithm, search, full-text-search

Are there any silver bullets out there for searching medium sized amounts of text data (hundreds of gigabytes)? Don't really care if it's commercial or open source. I should add that I need it to be C++ or C based.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is a commonly used indexing engine, not sure if it qualifies as a silver bullet or not. I've seen this combined with [Carrot2](http://search.carrot2.org/stable/search) for clustering and search of the index.

Comment: Is there a C++ implementation of Carrot2?

Comment: I don't think so, but Lucene is open-source as is Carrot2 - http://sourceforge.net/projects/carrot2/ so you could see how it works/implement a C++ version? I've always used the Java ones - never needed C++.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [xapian](http://xapian.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Solr could also be an option. This is also a Lucene based engine.

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/